# parsing JSON on appcelerator

Tags: json, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i have a webservice like this:

```
{"person":{"name account":"Jhon Doe","Image":"image/test","Adress":"New York 43","Recomendations":"40"}}
```

this is what i'm trying to do, when i print `datos` i get the whole json but when i try to print just the name or Image i don't get anything

```
var urll = "example.com/example";
var json;
var xhrr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
        json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var datos = JSON.stringify(json);
        var medicos = datos;
        Ti.API.info("Json! "+datos);
}
});
xhrr.open('GET', urll);
xhrr.send();
```

i tried with `datos[0].person`, `datos.person` but nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to understand the difference between a string that contains a JSON ***representation*** of an object - and the object itself.

Your `json` variable contains the object (which is what `JSON.parse(...)` does - convert a text string to an object). On the object you can refer to the attributes as you discovered. You can do this in two ways:

```
json.person.Address
json.person['name account']
```

I would suggest that you try to avoid attributes with names that are not valid identifiers (as the latter of the two) as this makes it a little more difficult to use them - e.g. by not allowing the dot notation.

Your `datos` variable on the other hand contains the string representation of the `json` object (as `JSON.stringify(...)` does exactly that - convert an object to its string representation). This means that datos is the same as this.responseText (since you first `parse` it and then `stringify` it back).

So `JSON.stringify(...)` is a brilliant way to make the object "*human readable*" but you need the object to work with the data.

Hope this clarifies the terms a little ;-)

/John

Comment: Absolutely right - to simplify this, you don't need to use JSON.stringify() after you have already used JSON.parse().

Answer (score 1):

i just find the solution:

```
Ti.API.info("Json! "+json.person.Recomendations);
```